# Mapbox iOS - Custom annotations are invisible

Tags: ios, maps, mapbox

I'm trying to create simple custom map annotations on **Mapbox iOS (5.5.0)** by implementing *MGLMapViewDelegate* protocol. Annotations are actually added to the map, but they are invisible. I can predict its coordinate and open its callout, so, I know it's there.

I have even tried copying the exact codes given on Mapbox examples to get the same result. Can it be a lack of some framework elements?

### My code:

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Set the map’s size, style, center coordinate, zoom level, and tint color.
        let mapView = MGLMapView(frame: view.bounds)
        let coordinates = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.4561, longitude: 49.7263)

        mapView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        mapView.styleURL = MGLStyle.darkStyleURL(withVersion: 9)
        mapView.setCenter(coordinates, zoomLevel: 15, animated: false)
        //mapView.userTrackingMode = .followWithHeading
        //mapView.showsUserHeadingIndicator = true


        view.addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.delegate = self


        let marker = MGLPointAnnotation()

        marker.coordinate = coordinates
        marker.title = "Area 51"
        marker.subtitle = "There is no way in!"

        mapView.addAnnotation(marker)
    }

    // Use the default marker. See also: our view annotation or custom marker examples.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, viewFor annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> MGLAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is MGLPointAnnotation else {
            return nil
        }

        let annotationAvailable = isAnnotationAvailable(annotation)
        let reuseIdentifier = "\(annotationAvailable)"

        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if (annotationView == nil) {
            annotationView = MGLAnnotationView()
            annotationView = CustomAnnotationView(reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
            annotationView!.bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 40, height: 40)

            if (!annotationAvailable) {
                annotationView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 255, green: 0, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            }
            else {
                annotationView!.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 0, green: 255, blue: 0, alpha: 1)
            }


        }
        return annotationView
    }

    // Allow callout view to appear when an annotation is tapped.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotationCanShowCallout annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func isAnnotationAvailable(_ annotation: MGLAnnotation) -> Bool {
        return false
    }
}

class CustomAnnotationView: MGLAnnotationView {
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        // Use CALayer’s corner radius to turn this view into a circle.
        layer.cornerRadius = bounds.width / 2
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Animate the border width in/out, creating an iris effect.
        let animation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "borderWidth")
        animation.duration = 0.1
        layer.borderWidth = selected ? bounds.width / 4 : 2
        layer.add(animation, forKey: "borderWidth")
    }
}
```

### The result:

[Mapbox Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xnbNV.png)

Comment: Your `viewFor annotation` method is obviously returning nil for some reason. Have you tried adding a breakpoint and stepping through the method, checking values as you go?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code! I ran your code and was able to see the annotation. Could you share more information about how to reproduce this behavior? Are you seeing it with specific iOS or device versions?